# What are different measures that say something about a given dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, dataset

Given a data set (having *n* instances and *m* features), what are the different measures that give some insight about some properties of the data set?

In other words, if there are two such data sets, are there any measures that talk about similarity/difference between the data sets?

Thank you.

Comment: Your question seems pretty broad (i.e., how do you analyse data?). This whole site is devoted to answering that question. Could you say a bit more about the goals of such an analysis?

Comment: Any analysis which can give results like, for this data set, value of property X is _some number_, will do.

Comment: It sounds like you are not trying to describe a dataset, you are trying to describe how similar two groups are on a set of variables, where the group is implicitly defined by which dataset the case is currently in.

Answer (score 2):

The first thing I would do is trying to visualize the datasets. Start to plot histograms of all the features. That will tell you much more than some sterile numbers, also about the similarity of the two datasets. Furthermore plot the correlations between two features, either 2D-histograms, profile plots or scatter plots. After that you will have quite a good feeling, much better than "0.794 similarity".

EDIT:

If you would like to automatize the procedure, here is an idea:
It is more or less a classification problem. Can I classify if a sample is from dataset A or B given the features. The similarity is then the separation power of the classifier. If the classifier is able to separate the items from A from the items of B, then the two datasets are quite different. If it is not possible, the datasets are more or less the same.

There are several metrics describing the separation power, a starting point is wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_classification#Evaluation. These metrics normally depend on the prior ratio of A and B, therefore you need to correct for this if your datasets are different in size, see e.g. [Uncertainty_coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uncertainty_coefficient). As a classifier you can use any algorithm out there, neural networks, svm, boosted decision trees, ... Just choose one or try several.

Comment: Sorry, but still I would like something that can say "0.794 similarity".

Comment: Then you need to clarify more, what you want to do and why you need this. Do you want to automatize this for thousands of different datasets? Do you want to find clusters of datasets? Or someone wants this number from you regardless of the reasonableness?

Comment: Okay, the first two questions in your comment above are the reasons to do this analysis.

Comment: I updated my answer